# consumir un servicio PHP en Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

Estoy tratando de consumir un Servicio desde Android, y no me marca error pero tampoco me muestra los registros

**Mi Codigo PHP**
Cambié mi Código PHP  y aun no puedo obtener los registros.

```
    <?php
    $consulta=$_GET["Code"]
    try{ 
    $usuario = "xxxxxxx"; 
    $password = "xxxxx"; 
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxxxx;dbname=xxxxx', $usuario, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

   $sql="SELECT Code,user,Pass,TipoUsuario FROM Usuarios WHERE Code= :Code";
    $resultado=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $resultado ->execute(array($consulta));
    $registro=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json=json_encode($registro);

    return $json;

   }catch(PDOException $e){ 
     echo 'No existe  un usuario  con este código'; 
   }
?>
```

**Este es   mi clase Config.**

```
//URL  DE  MI CÓDIGO  PHP
    public static final String URL_ADD_USER="http://ejemplo.atwebpages.com/conect/addUser.php";
    public static final String URL_GET_USER = "http://ejemplo.atwebpages.com/conect/busquedaUser.php?Code=";


  // obtengo valores
   public static final String KEY_USER_CODE = "Code";
   public static final String KEY_USER_USUARIO = "user";
   public static final String KEY_USER_PASS = "Pass";
   public static final String KEY_USER_TIPOUSER = "TipoUsuario";

   // El result
    public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";
```

**Este es  mi código  Java.**

```
 private void getData() {
    String Code= et1.getText().toString().trim();
    if (Code.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    String url = Config.URL_GET_USER+et1.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(buscarUpdateUser.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
private void showJSON(String response){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        String  User = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_USER_USUARIO);
        String Pass = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_USER_PASS);
        String TipoUsuario = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_USER_TIPOUSER);

        et2.setText(User);
        et3.setText(Pass);
        SeleccionaItemTipoUsuario(tipUser,TipoUsuario);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Tu consulta no te regresa ningun registro? ¿Ya probaste tu consulta MYSQL? ¿En que parte se pierde?

Comment: M.Gress ese es el problema, simplemente  busco los registros  y no  me  los  muestra, tampoco  errores.

Comment: Tal vez la respuesta no obtiene ningún dato. verifica si obtienes datos aquí : public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }

Comment: @Jorgesys  ya  hice  lo que  me pediste, de todas maneras  sigue  sin mostrarme  los registros.

Comment: Falta un } antes del catch. A lo mejor no es solo eso, pero prueba.

Comment: este parece un tipico error de [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), tienes habilitado el acceso en tu PHP (https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/102186/28035)??

Answer (score 2):

Tu código espera un resultado de tipo cadena, pero formateado al estilo JSON:

```
    public void onResponse(String response) {
```

Dicho resultado, llamado `response`es enviado en parámetro al método:

```
        showJSON(response);
```

el cual lo convierte en un objeto JSON:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

**El problema:**

Desde tu PHP, el cual consultas enviando la URL, no estás devolviendo lo que android espera, es decir, una cadena en forma de JSON.

Algo más o menos así:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

Si vas a esta URL verás un ejemplo de un servicio web funcionando correctamente: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 Si tu servicio web (PHP) funciona bien, debería devolver algo parecido.

**Solución:**

Tu código PHP necesita un retoque. Esta parte del código:

```
$sql="SELECT Code,user,Pass,TipoUsuario FROM Usuarios";
$resultado=$conn->prepare($sql);
$resultado ->execute();
while($registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo Code.$registro[0];
    echo user. $registro[1];
    echo Pass.$registro[2];
    echo TipoUsuario.$registro[3];
```

Es más simple. Sería algo así más o menos:

```
$sql="SELECT Code,user,Pass,TipoUsuario FROM Usuarios";
$resultado=$conn->prepare($sql);
$resultado ->execute();
/*
 * Esto sobra
 * while($registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 * {
 *   echo Code.$registro[0];
 *   echo user. $registro[1];
 *   echo Pass.$registro[2];
 *   echo TipoUsuario.$registro[3];


/*
 * Si Android espera un JSON, lo construyes aquí
 * Simplemente convirtiendo los datos recibidos
 * a JSON, usando json_encode
 *
 */
$registro=$resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($registro);

/* Estas dos líneas son muyyyy importantes. Tu código devuelve el JSON a Android */
header('Content-Type: application/json');
return $json;
```

Debería funcionar, a no ser que haya otro error en el código o que el servidor no esté devolviendo nada desde PHP. Eso lo puedes probar haciendo `System.out.println` del resultado que recibes.

**¿Aún no muestra nada después de estos cambios?**

Prueba a enviar la URL a tu servicio web desde el navegador tal y como la envías desde android. Si te devuelve un JSON parecido al ejemplo de más arriba, el código de `showJSON(response);` ha de ser revisado, quizá no estés parseando bien el JSON recibido. Si al poner la URL en el navegador no ves los resultados de tipo JSON, es muy posible que por algún motivo la consulta SQL no esté devolviendo nada.

Comment: te faltaria añadir en el PHP el content-type de retorno

Comment: Ciertamente @JackNavaRow, se me había escapado ese detalle, gracias por haberlo advertido.

Answer (score 1):

Yo he tenido muchas veces el mismo problema y encuentro que las tildes y caracteres extraños siempre son el problema.

Revisa la salida del `json_encode()`, si es falsa el problema está en los datos que consultas.

Siempre procura pasar la salida (los datos) a `UTF-8` antes de pasarla al `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 0):

El error es de tu servidor de php.
Pon este código encima de tu consulta php:

```html
function get_result( $stmt ) {
    $arrResult = array();
    $stmt->store_result();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $stmt->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $metadata = $stmt->result_metadata();
        $arrParams = array();
        while ( $field = $metadata->fetch_field() ) {
            $arrParams[] = &$arrResult[ $i ][ $field->name ];
        }
        call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, 'bind_result' ), $arrParams );
        $stmt->fetch();
    }
    return $arrResult;
}
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).