# Problema de Cors, en Ajax con PHP

Tags: php, ajax, cors

alguien sabe porque se origina este error?
Estoy llamando por ajax a un archivo, y en la consola sale eso. El que llama y el que recibe están en el mismo dominio. lo que llama es una lista para un select, si lo abro desde la URL directo si se responde la lista.

Failed to load **: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '**' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGQcG.png

Comment: https://imgur.com/O1DQTLB

Comment: brother, aprecio que le agregues imagenes sin embargo, sería más efectivo para ti y para nosotros que tu pregunta contenga código, así nos motivas a reproducir el escenario donde estás. Considerando que eres nuevo usuario, date una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Bienvenido a la hermandad :D

Comment: @normalito1212 además de los consejos de Fredyfx, revisa [ask] y [answer], la sección de respuestas es exclusivamente para respuestas, si lo que sugiere en su respuesta abrahamstalin te ayudo a resolver el problema puedes marcarla como la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 2):

Agrega lo siguiente al inicio de tu servicio en PHP, esto te puede servir en pruebas:

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Con esto estarás permitiendo las peticiones desde cualquier dominio.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he visto ese aviso en otros casos, el servidor de donde estás obteniendo el servicio tiene la política de control de acceso de origen, lo cual no te deja consumir el servicio si no es desde el propio sitio.
Por lo tanto si estas intentando consumir el servicio desde tu pc por ejemplo, no lo permitirá dando el dichoso aviso.

Aquí te dejo un enlace donde explican esto y algunas posibles soluciones.

http://www.cantabriatic.com/cross-domain-y-peticiones-ajax-limitacion-o-seguridad/

Espero te sirva, saludos.